# MVC 4 Delete Action with Success and Fail Actions

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

What would be the best method in your opinion to handle Deleting an item.

Below is a code example of my initial thoughts but the problem is a `return RedirectToAction("Index")` loses the context so the Index doesn't know that the Role couldn't be deleted because there are users attached to it.

So if it can't be deleted I can show a message contained in a hidden div or even a method with an alert to let the user know why it couldn't be deleted but the Index should be aware of the problem.

I'd prefer not to use Session or ViewData.
I had attempted to use an `@Ajax.ActionLink()` but was always getting a GET request.

jQuery 1.7.1 is available for use.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Delete(string roleName)
{
    RoleProvider roleProvider = new SARoleProvider();
    bool isDelete = roleProvider.DeleteRole(roleName, true);

    if (isDelete)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { roleName = item.Role }, new { @class = "confirmDelete btn btn-danger btn-mini", onclick = "return confirm('Delete this item?');" })
```

Comment: The easiest solution is to store a message in the TempData dictionary which will be available (only) on the subsequent request. However, this does make uses of session state.

Comment: @eulerfx I also should have mentioned I'd prefer not to use TempData as well but if this is the best way I can see if it's an approved method.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://maxtoroq.blogspot.com/2012/08/implementing-delete-button-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the jQuery post to send and receive the information I needed based on whether the item could be deleted or not.

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="alert alert-error" id="DeleteError">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <span>There was a problem deleting the Role. Please check that there are no Users in the Role and try again or contact an Administrator.</span>
</div>


@Html.Raw("<a href=\"javascript:deleteRole('" + item.Role + "');\" class=\"confirmDelete btn btn-danger btn-mini\">Delete</a>")


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#DeleteError').hide();
    });

    function deleteRole(roleName) {

        if (confirm('Delete the item?')) {

            // Begin the request
            $.post('@Url.Action("Delete")/?roleName=' + roleName, {}, function(data) {
                if (data.IsDeleted) {
                    // Refresh the page
                    window.location.reload();
                } else if (data.IsError) {
                    $("#DeleteError").show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Controller.cs

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
    public JsonResult Delete(string roleName)
    {
        bool isError = false;
        bool isDeleted = Roles.Provider.DeleteRole(roleName, true);

        if (!isDeleted)
        {
            isError = true;
        }

        return Json(new { IsDeleted = isDeleted, IsError = isError }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```